# Error while trying to assign Company Id to Account members Using Forge BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I tried to use postman to assign default company ID using the
PATCH https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id TO users. But it only works for a couple users and for most I get an error saying "code":1006,"message":"You have reached the maximum number of members for BIM 360 Docs and Design Collaboration"
and I'm not sure what the problem is or how to get around this.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: From the error message, you should reach the limitation of the user within the company, are your using the trial version of BIM 360? Could you please also try with the UI to see if this behavior could be also reproduced from UI, and you can contact bim360appsactivations@autodesk.com to ask for increasing the number.

Comment: Hey @ZhongWu, Thank you for your comment but no our BIM360 is not a trial version (we have 500 seats) but have many more collaborators(from different companies who share models). I'm able to change the company id of each individual if I click into their profile and edit their company (but its too laborious since I can change only one at a time).